# Is there an alternative way to open file without its path in ELM Fatfs?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, embedded, fat

I want to open file files without their path in ELM Fatfs.
I want to store a pointer or something and use that to open files or folders rather than their paths.
This will save me alot of ram in a stm32.
My current application store file paths and use that to open music files which has restricted me to a 256 file path length limit and 512 files.
an array of [512][256]
Is there any way that I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The whole point of a file system is that things don't need to have a fixed address you know to access them; you get the current location of data blocks from the path.

So, you will need to keep the path.

> a 256 file path length limit and 512 files. an array of [512][256]

1. You got an off-by-one error there which will lead to corruption if a file name is actually 256 B long, because you have no space to store the terminating zero-byte. Classic bug recipe for a buffer overflow!
2. Anyways, you're using a fixed length for each path, but most paths will not be maximum length. Your fixed-length array is wasting a lot of space.

Since paths are inherently hierarchical, a better storage method might actually be a tree structure, where your nodes represent files as on your file system, and the full path of the file can be derived from the node's position in the tree, the node's ancestor path, and the node's own content.

Also, your playlist probably also resides on the external storage. Technically, there's no reason to ever have it completely in RAM at once; you might simply be able to open the playlist file, and seek in it as necessary.

Both solutions probably require quite a bit of re-architecting your firmware – but you've hit a memory wall, and such walls are quite hard :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I check the file length for avoiding buffer overflows that's not my problem really that has been handled. I need to have a directory list because my media player has file browsing function functionality which user can select a file from a folder by knob. I agree to your point for changing data structure but changing this part of the firmware requires building entire file and folder scan from ground up just  to achieve this.

Comment: well, I explained to options to achieve that: to draw something on a screen, you neither need to store the strings as fixed-length array of fixed-length arrays, nor do you need to store the full file list in RAM – that's simply not the case.

Comment: There is no playlist file. I will scan  USB MSC and by storing folders which have a song, in the Folder array. Then I will open a folder and Scan all the songs and store them in the playlist Array . Each time I just open a folder and scan that folders songs to Maximum file number of 512.

Comment: yes, so, then don't do that copying of paths into the array. It's really not necessary, architecturally. It might seem comfortable, but it's eating too much RAM: directly use the entries of your directory listing for display purposes. No need for your array.

Comment: I not understanding why its not necessary how could I access a folder if I don't know its a path and I didn't store its path to open its directory.  f_opendir(DIR* dp,const TCHAR* path) this function needs. In my application I need to know how many directories is available.

Comment: to know how many you have, you just go through the directory and count up an integer. at no point do you need to have all contained files in RAM! That's  not how `f_readdir` works: it advances the directory entry object by one with every call.

Comment: That's Really a good suggestion but a problem which arises is if i want to sort files I cant do this

Comment: that's also not true; say you have N spaces for files you want to display on your display; you only need a container for N+1 paths; you can always when you scroll, go through the directory again, and sort on the fly (according to whichever criteria you like to use for sorting) to find the N files following the last direntry "above"; the +1th entry is to save the current top entry.

Comment: Your comments have given me an idea to fix this memory problem and based your fact it is a viable solution. thanks alot